# LaTeX issues warning about a Reference being undefined even though a \label statement was issued

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, tags

I want to show a few equations in a row as I solve an integration, then number the final unsimplified equation and use the number in the next line.

```
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
...
\begin{gather*}
  \left[\frac12x-\frac1{4n}\sin2nx\right]_a^{a+2\pi}\\
  \frac{a+2\pi}2-\frac1{4n}\sin(2n(a+2\pi))-\frac{a}2+\frac1{4n}\sin(2an)\\
  \frac{a+2\pi}2-\frac{a}2+\frac1{4n}\sin(2an)-\frac1{4n}\sin(2an+4n\pi)\numberthis\label{unsimplified integral of sine squared}\\
  \sin(x+2\pi)\equiv\sin(x)\implies\ref{unsimplified integral of sine squared}=\frac{a+2\pi-a}2
\end{gather*}
```

This gives me the error

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `unsimplified integral of sine squared' on page 6 undefined

Comment: [tag:labels] is *not* meant for issues with `\label` ;-)

Comment: Off-topic: I would use `\eqref` instead of `\ref` to create the cross-reference to the numbered equation.

Comment: @Mico why's that? And how do I implement it if it has advantages?

Comment: @theonlygusti - If you change `\ref` to `\eqref`, LaTeX will encase the number `1` in parentheses. This might be helpful to your readers, who might otherwise be puzzling over the apparent claim that `1=\pi`...

Comment: @Mico I was going to just write the brackets myself. Using eqref looks better though, i assume it was designed for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism employs the `\refstepcounter` macro to (a) increment the specified counter and (b) enable the argument of `\label` to be associated with the most-recently-incremented counter variable.

Thus, simply change

```
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

to

```
\newcommand\numberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}
```

and you're in business.

Comment: Perfect, will accept in 3 mins. Super concise yet thorough, that's pretty awesome actually!

Comment: @theonlygusti: The 3 mins have passed ... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You got the OP's attention! :-)